# Seems that I have a wrong index somewhere, but cannot spot it

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am new to python and having trouble with a function. It should delete rows of a (N,10) matrix (imported fron a file) where -1 appears. This is the code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
def load(name, f):

    file = pd.read_csv(name,header=None)

    totalMatrix = np.array(file)

    if f == 'forward':

        for i in range(len(totalMatrix)):

            for j in range(10):

                if totalMatrix[i,j] ==-1: 

                    if i > 0:
                        totalMatrix[i,j]=totalMatrix[i-1,j]

                    else:
                        print("Warning")
                        f = 'drop'


    elif f == 'drop':

        for i in range(len(totalMatrix)): # or np.size(totalMatrix[:, 0])

            for j in range(10):

                if totalMatrix[i,j] == -1 : 

                    totalMatrix = np.delete(totalMatrix, (i), axis=0)


    t = totalMatrix[:, 0:6]
    d = totalMatrix[:, 6:11]

    return t, d
```

But I keep running on this error:

```
line 38, in load
if totalMatrix[i,j] == -1 :

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

I have tried to look several places on internet, but could not find an answer, neither could I find the error myself. Can anybody see what is wrong and tell me?

Comment: The problem is that you **alter the matrix while iterating**. You `np.delete(..)` a row, but you keep iterating. That is bad design.

Comment: You can't delete an item while iterating. It changes the size of the list, which means that an index equal to the original size ends up being invalid when you get to the end of the list. Think it through: You have 10 items, so valid indexes range from 0 to 9. At index 5, you remove an item, which means valid indexes now end at 8, but your loop is running to 9. You run off then end. If you're going to delete items, iterate backward (from high to low); you won't run off the list if you delete one, although you may process one twice.

Comment: But if I have 10 columns, and I delete a row, how does it affect the iteration? And what does it change to iterate backward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because the matrix is getting smaller and you keep iterating based on the old size, i.e. if the totalMatrix has 3 rows in the beginning and you delete one, the last iteration will try to get a nonexisting row.

While iterating on the Matrix, gather the indices you want to delete. Afterward, you can delete them at once.

```
 toDelete = []
 for i in range(len(totalMatrix)): # or np.size(totalMatrix[:, 0])
     for j in range(10):
         if totalMatrix[i,j] == -1 : 
             toDelete.append(i)
 totalMatrix = np.delete(totalMatrix, i, axis=0)
```